# Identify tree with bright magenta flowers and grayish leaves

Tags: identification, trees, flowers, rhododendrons, azaleas

Blooms around May in the Pacific Northwest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a *Rhododendron* of some variety; rhododendrons used to be split between azaleas and rhododendron, but now they are all classed as rhododendron. What used to be known as azalea types usually have smaller leaves which may or may not be deciduous, and they do not tend to have such large clusters of flowers held as one head as is visible on your image. From what little foliage I can see, the leaves also appear somewhat large for an azalea  type, but it would be easier to tell if the flowers were not present. As to the varietal name of the plant, there are literally thousands of rhododendron varieties with flowers ranging in colour from whites to yellows to orange through to pale to deep pinks and purples. There are several varieties with deep pink flowers, so identifying quite which variety you're showing here is next to impossible. This link https://www.greenandvibrant.com/types-of-rhododendron shows 13 different types of rhododendron - there are hundreds if not thousands more.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question; it appears to be a cultivar of a *tsutsuji* Azalea, in the genus *Rododendron*. Some Azalea cultivars can be 6-8m in height, though typically they're 1-2m. There are thousands of different Azalea varieties, and Azaleas have been cultivated since ancient times. Also, could be helpful if could include a closer illustration of flowers, and also the approximate leaf size & overall height